# C++ STL, I wonder what is different between bidirectional iterator and operator[] in map

Tags: c++, stl

I learned it is different between random access iterator and bidirectional iterator.
random access iterator can use  `+, -, += , -=, []` operator but bidirectional iterator can't.
map use bidirectional iterator. But map still use `[]` operator.

for example:

```
map<int,int> a;
a[5]++;
```

it works well.

I don't understand what this do.

By any chance, can you tell me how?

Comment: `a[5]` is not an iterator, is logarithm access (instead of O(1))

Comment: `map a;` is `map` supposed to be `std::map`? If so, it's invalid C++ syntax, since `std::map` is a template, and `map a;` is missing template arguments. What `a[5]++;` does (or whether it's valid), depends on those.

Comment: Why do you think the `[]` of`std::map` is related to iterator categories?

Comment: `a[5]++` increments the value in the map for the key `5`. If you apply `operator++` to an iterator something completely different will happen. You are comparing apples with oranges

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Bad markdown. Good practice is to always check the question source when the user is new and template arguments are missing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fair enough. I tend to forget that this might be the case, if I don't notice signs, that suggest, that this is the case (e.g. bold `#include` statements).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Yep :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> random access iterator can use  +, -, += , -=, [] operator but bidirectional iterator can't.

That's an oversimplification, and you've discovered why.

A bidirectional iterator can't perform *random access operations*. For some containers, `[]` is a random access operation. It takes you some "distance" into the container.

For an associative container like a map, though, it isn't: it's an operation specifically designed for those containers. It takes a *key* and gives you a *value*. It's a different operation.

Try to think in terms of *features* and *behaviours* rather than of symbols, because symbols take different meanings depending on the context. If you want to learn what a symbol means in some given context, you can refer to [a reference](https://cppreference.com) or to [your book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: nitpick: "A bidirectional iterator" -> "something that is *only* bidirectional iterator", random access implies bidirectional

Comment: @Caleth Granted. For this level of discussion I think I'll leave it alone, but if I can think of a way to describe that cascading property of iterator categories without confusing the heck out of the OP I may :) I personally wouldn't call a RA iterator "bidirectional" even though it does inherit the properties of a bidirectional iterator via the BidirectionalIterator category. Same way I wouldn't call a `float` an integer, even though it's capable of holding natural numbers.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to your kind explanation, I could understand.I confused what is different between vector's [] and map's []. now, I clearly know what is diffrent. Please make sure I know exactly what you're saying. vector's [] operator is to return size and map's [] operator is to return value. right? if you say me "you are right", I can sleep.

Comment: @조민국 They both return a value ;) But they do it in different ways. Vector's requires "random access", whereas map's doesn't, because the ways of getting to the data are so different.

Answer (score 2):

pointers support `[]`, which is defined as `p[i]` being equivalent to `*(p + i)`. *RandomAccessIterator*s are things that behave like pointers, so they also support that, with the same meaning.

A number of *containers* also support `[]`. Of these, there are two kinds.

The first kind are those [*SequenceContainer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SequenceContainer)s who's iterators are [*RandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), and the parameter to `SequenceContainer::operator[]` is `std::size_t`, i.e. something that identifies an element by it's position in the sequence. `vec[i]` is the same as `vec.begin()[i]` is the same as `*(vec.begin() + i)`.

If you can easily find an element at a particular index, your iterators can easily be incremented or decremented by an offset larger than 1.

The second kind are those [*AssociativeContainer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AssociativeContainer)s or [*UnorderedAssociativeContainers*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnorderedAssociativeContainer)s that have a `mapped_type`. The parameter to `AssociativeContainer::operator[]` is `AssociativeContainer::key_type`, i.e. something that identifies an element by it's value.

Easily finding an element with a particular value doesn't help with moving along a sequence. It turns out that the currently known data-structures that allow easy access by value are not as good at knowing which element is `n` further along.

Comment: @PeteBecker oops, fixed

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Thanks to you, I know what I'm missing.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice this before. Sequence containers don't categorically provide random access iterators. `std::list` provides bidirectional iterators, and `std::forward_list` provides forward iterators. The defining characteristic of a sequence container is that the you control the order of elements in the container; associative containers make their own decisions about the order.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, there are other *SequenceContainer*s, which are only bidirectional (or forward), which is exactly the demarcation between "has []" and "lacks []"

Comment: Oh, I see: you're restricting those paragraphs to containers that support []. Okay.

Comment: Yes, also the *Associative*s that are map-like, rather than set-like. It would be nice if we had standardese for these subgroups, for situations like this.